# Armazenando valores de x e y em uma função y=sex(x)

Tags: python, matemática

Estou trabalhando no abaqus e preciso dentro da função de cut extrude programar uma função seno para desenhar a curva e cortar a peça.

o código do abaqus quando fiz o desenho da primeira curva manualmente é esse:

```
mdb.models['Model-2'].ConstrainedSketch(gridSpacing=124.78, name='__profile__', 
    sheetSize=4991.52, transform=
    mdb.models['Model-2'].parts['Part-1'].MakeSketchTransform(
    sketchPlane=mdb.models['Model-2'].parts['Part-1'].faces[26], 
    sketchPlaneSide=SIDE1, 
    sketchUpEdge=mdb.models['Model-2'].parts['Part-1'].edges[2], 
    sketchOrientation=RIGHT, origin=(0.0, 210.5, 4000.0)))
mdb.models['Model-2'].parts['Part-1'].projectReferencesOntoSketch(filter=
    COPLANAR_EDGES, sketch=mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'])
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(
    12.27, 0.46))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(12.27, 0.46), 
    point2=(24.55, 1.82))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(24.55, 1.82), 
    point2=(36.82, 4.07))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(36.82, 4.07), 
    point2=(49.09, 7.14))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(49.09, 7.14), 
    point2=(61.37, 10.99))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(61.37, 10.99), 
    point2=(73.64, 15.53))
mdb.models['Model-2'].sketches['__profile__'].Line(point1=(73.64, 15.53), 
    point2=(85.91, 20.67))
```

Apliquei em outro modelo e ele funciona, desenha a mesma curva.
Mas preciso programar com variáveis para ele desenhar curvas em função de variáveis q eu substitua. Estou tentando o seguinte código mas não esta indo.

```
a0=180.0
ls=270.0
w=140.0
x_i=0
y_i=0

while x_i < 270: 
    
    y_i=0.25*a0*(sin(3.14*((x_i/ls)+1.5))+1)
    x_i=x_i+12.273

print(x_i,y_i)
```

print no final era pra tentar printar o vetor e ver se calculou todos os pontos certo, mas ele ta mostrando só o ultimo ponto.

tentei usando comando FOR mas não deu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar uma lista para armazenar cada valor calculado, por exemplo.

```py
a0=180.0
ls=270.0
w=140.0
x_i=0
y_i=0
xs = []
ys = []

while x_i < 270: 
    y_i=0.25*a0*(sin(3.14*((x_i/ls)+1.5))+1)
    x_i=x_i+12.273
    xs.append(x_i)
    ys.append(y_i)

print(xs, ys)
```

Ou você pode mostrar na tela cada valor.

```py
a0=180.0
ls=270.0
w=140.0
x_i=0
y_i=0

while x_i < 270: 
    y_i=0.25*a0*(sin(3.14*((x_i/ls)+1.5))+1)
    x_i=x_i+12.273
    print(x_i,y_i)
```

Contudo, isso não faz nada ser desenhado em tela. Você ainda precisará pensar em alguma forma de chamar as funções do abaqus para fazer isso.